# Why does React.createPortal allow key like list items, whereas other things like <Suspense> doesn't?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-suspense, react-key-index

I have seen some apis in ReactJs to allow *keys*, e.g. `<React.Fragment>`, but at the same time `<React.Suspense>` doesn't have keys.

Now specifically why does [`React.createPortal`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) allow key like list items?

My research: I didn't find much on SO or google, but I found [one discussion on github](https://github.com/reactjs/react.dev/issues/5927), which seem to imply that *keys* were added in the documentation after 18 April 2023.

Comment: Where did you get the information that Suspense does not accept key prop?

Comment: @OktayYuzcan From the api I assumed that https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense#suspense

Comment: the key is a prop that works everywhere in React, it doesn't need to be explicitly added to every component in the documentation. The key indicates if the component should be rendered when comparing components in the tree.

Comment: What makes you think that you can't write `<React.Suspense key="…">`?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, I find the [current React documentation](https://react.dev/) **a little thin** in some areas myself.

I also can't find an explicit statement regarding the `key` property in [JSX elements](https://react.dev/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx) there *(I can't prove the non-existence of anything, so forgive me if I missed it and feel free to comment)*.

#### React.createElement()

**UPDATE 2023-07-19:**

This section about `createElement()` is probably outdated.
JSX syntax is apparently not converted to `createElement` anymore (React v18), but instead to a call to an internal `jsx()` function, which seems not to be supposed to be called by the developer, I believe defined in [/src/jsx/ReactJSXElement.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/jsx/ReactJSXElement.js):

***Previous answer:***

Anyway, knowing that **JSX is converted to [`React.createElement(...)`](https://react.dev/reference/react/createElement)** calls *(which, to my surprise, is mentioned under ["Legacy React APIs"](https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy))*, I can see that `props` passed to `createElement` will handle a `props.key` property in a special way:

> Note that `ref` and `key` from your `props` object are special and will not be available as `element.props.ref` and `element.props.key` on the returned `element`. They will be available as `element.ref` and `element.key`.

Also note the [legacy `createElement` documentation](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement):

> Code written with JSX will be converted to use `React.createElement()`.

##### Deduction

That is a *general* statement about `createElement`, so
**every element created by `createElement` should allow the `key` property**.

Assuming that it is still true that every JSX element is a `createElement` call, as it was in the past *(the word "legacy" suggests it might change)*, this implies that every JSX element accepts a `key` prop.

So it seems "clear" to me that **every JSX element accepts a `key`**, but in my opinion it should be stated more explicitly.

#### <React.Fragment>

I guess that the documentation mentions [`key` in `<React.Fragment>`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment) explicitly,
because it's a common question how to add a `key` to a fragment, because a fragment is more commonly written using the empty-brackets-syntax `<>`, where you can not add any properties. But that's just a guess.

#### React.createPortal()

[React.createPortal()](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) is different, because it is not JSX syntax, so it needs a specific documentation.

#### Rendering Lists

The section ["Rendering Lists"](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) mentions `key` properties, but I find this not sufficient to answer your question.

It is solely focused on keys in "list items" / "collections" / "arrays", and doesn't say anything about the `key` property in general.

Comment: Thanks mate. I am kinda reading both the legacy and the new docs at the same time, just for the sake of completeness.